# Python - mail returns "mail: You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b"

Tags: python, email, python-2.7

Python script returns error when using `subprocess.call()` to send mail:

```
>>> cmd = "echo 'Hi' | mail -aFrom:something@example.com -s 'Password change'" + user.email
>>> subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
mail: You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b
1
```

sending mail from terminal works OK:

```
echo "hi" | mail -aFrom:something@example.com -s "Password change" me@example.com
```

Are there some options missing?

**EDIT:**
I've edited it to use python smtplib library and now it sends error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u011b' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`

code:

```
        msg = MIMEText("HI, ččšššěř")
        msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr((user.username, user.email))
        msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('ASDF', 'author@example.com'))
        msg['Subject'] = "Password change"

        try:
           server = smtplib.SMTP('mail')
           server.set_debuglevel(True) # show communication with the server
           server.sendmail('test@example.com', [user.email], msg.as_string())
           print "Successfully sent email"
           return u"Email has been sent."
        except SMTPException:
           return "Error: unable to send email"
```

I'm using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Why are you sending mail via subprocess rather than using the [Python libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)?

Comment: OK, exactly where are you getting that error? What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a space in line `cmd = "echo 'Hi' | mail -aFrom:something@example.com -s 'Password change'" + user.email`  after 'Password change'. Seems that user.email value goes to the email subject in your case.

Try:

`cmd = "echo 'Hi' | mail -aFrom:something@example.com -s 'Password change' " + user.email`